# How to visualize JVM working on linux?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, garbage-collection, jvm, visualization

I didn't find any programs or tools like a VisualVM or Visual GC for linux. Is there any way to see it's work except JVM running arguments? I use an Intellij IDEA by the way. May be JetBrains has some plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running ubuntu you can simply

**"sudo apt-get install visualvm"**